# Iterating though Dictionary values is not working for me in Django on GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Data is a sorted Dict from `django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict`

```
{'test1': '-10', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '40', 'quiz3': '55'}
```

This Template Code:

```
{% for key1 in Data %}
       <td>key: {{ key1|capfirst }} - value: {{Data.key1}} - Data: {{ Data }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Yields:

```
key: Quiz1 - value: - Data: {'test1': '-10', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '40', 'quiz3': '55'}

key: Quiz2 - value: - Data: {'test1': '-10', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '40', 'quiz3': '55'}

key: Quiz3 - value: - Data: {'test1': '-10', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '40', 'quiz3': '55'}

key: Test1 - value: - Data: {'test1': '-10', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '40', 'quiz3': '55'}
```

I've tried the different examples in the Doc, but I'm stuck.

EDIT:

I tried this Code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    {% for key1 in Data %}
        <td>{{ key1|capfirst }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
<tr>
    {% for key2 in Data %}
        <td>key: {{ key2|capfirst }}| Data: {{Data.key2}}| Static Keyed: {{ Data.quiz1 }}| AllData: {{ Data }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
<tr>
    {% for key,value in Data %}
        <td>key: {{key}}: value: {{value}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

and this is the result:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
        <td>Quiz1</td>
        <td>Quiz2</td>
        <td>Quiz3</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key: Quiz1| Data: | Static Keyed: 65| AllData: {'test1': '56', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '75', 'quiz3': '25'}</td>
    <td>key: Quiz2| Data: | Static Keyed: 65| AllData: {'test1': '56', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '75', 'quiz3': '25'}</td>
    <td>key: Quiz3| Data: | Static Keyed: 65| AllData: {'test1': '56', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '75', 'quiz3': '25'}</td>
    <td>key: Test1| Data: | Static Keyed: 65| AllData: {'test1': '56', 'quiz1': '65', 'quiz2': '75', 'quiz3': '25'}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>key: : value: </td>
    <td>key: : value: </td>
    <td>key: : value: </td>
    <td>key: : value: </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The Data is there, but django won't let me use a variable as a key. My problem is that I want the table to grow dynamically with a changing number of test/grade pairs passed to it. Is this normal?

EDIT:

It turns out that I am using a different version of django than I thought i was using. This code will do what I am trying to do in version 0.96 of django:

```
<tr>
{% for data in Data.items %} 
    <td>{{data.0}}: {{data.1}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Thanks to everyone that helped, even though I initially gave the wrong info.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this . Previous solution will work only with django >1.0

```
{% for data in Data.items %}
     <td>key: {{ data.0 }}: value: {{ data.1 }}</td> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This indeed solved the problem! Thanks! I mislead everyone thinking that my version was 1.2. Now I just need to figure out how to get my django to work at version 1.2, but for now, I can use this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for key, value in Data.items %}
     <td>key: {{ key|capfirst }} - value: {{ value }} - Data: {{ Data }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When I try this code I get this:
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_0_96\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 536, in do_for
    raise TemplateSyntaxError, "'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed': %s" % token.contents
TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements with five words should end in 'reversed': for key, value in Data.items

Comment: This error message obviously contradicts what you say above about version 1.2.

Comment: Your right. But I have this code In my main:
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')

Comment: This is a straight install of 1.5.0 of GAE on a windows xp system. I'm going to go back and see why its not 1.2.

Comment: Ok, so that setting doesn't seem to change anything. I guess that means I'm running version .96

Answer (score -1):

If i'm not wrong, SortedDict inherits from Dict, i think you can use it in this way:

```
{% for key, value in Data %}
    <td>key: {{ key|capfirst }} - value: {{value}}</td>
{% endofr %}
```

But i'm afraid is not clear What are the values in your dict.

Comment: In the dict, The keys are 'test1' 'quiz1' 'quiz2' 'quiz3' and the values should be '-10' '65' '40' '55'

Comment: I tried your code, but it gives me blanks for the value variable.